# Horizontal Pod Autoscaler with Stackdriver Custom Metric in GKE fails with "Invalid metric name" error

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, google-cloud-stackdriver, hpa

We're trying to use a custom JVM metric (`jvm_memory_bytes_used{area="heap"}`) to scale a deployment in our GKE cluster using a Horizontal Pod Autoscaler (HPA).

**Setup:**

- Enabled Stackdriver Managed Prometheus
- Installed JMX Exporter on JVMs and configured it to export the desired metric
- Deployed the Stackdriver Adapter for Custom Metrics
- Created an HPA referencing the custom metric:

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-autoscale
  namespace: somenamespace
spec:
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
  - pods:
      metric:
        name: jvm_memory_bytes_used{area="heap"}  # Metric name in question
      target:
        averageValue: 2G
        type: AverageValue
  type: Pods
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-java-app
```

**Problem:**

The HPA creation fails with the following error:

```
Error 400: Invalid metric name: custom.googleapis.com/jvm_memory_bytes_used{area="heap"},
```

We've tried various combinations of quotes around the metric name and the area label, but none worked.

**Question:**

Is it possible to use this specific custom metric for HPA scaling in GKE? If so, what's the correct way to specify it in the HPA configuration?

Comment: Drive-by: Haven't used HPA with custom metrics. Are you able to enumerate the metric using e.g. [metrics expolorer](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/metrics-explorer)? If so, can you revise the metric config to include: `selector: {matchLabels{area: heap}}`? You've piqued my curiosity to try this. I'm actually surprised that it requires `custom.googleapis.com` as I'd naively (!?) assume it could use `prometheus.googleapis.com` for cluster metrics scraped by GMP.

Comment: See [HPA: auto-scaling on more specific metrics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#autoscaling-on-more-specific-metrics)

Comment: Could you try `prometheus.googleapis.com|jvm_memory_bytes_used|counter`?

https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/hpa#stackdriver-adapter

Comment: @Mark I tried `prometheus.googleapis.com|jvm_memory_bytes_used|counter`, got `Error 404: Could not find descriptor for metric ''prometheus.googleapis.com/jvm_memory_bytes_used/counter''.,`

Comment: @DazWilkin "Are you able to enumerate the metric using e.g. metrics expolorer?" —
I enumerated them in the autocomplete from the builder: https://imgur.com/a/g7P8nhi. Found `prometheus.googleapis.com/jvm_memory_bytes_used/gauge`. HPA accepted it: `the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from pods metric prometheus.googleapis.com|jvm_memory_bytes_used|gauge`. But I don't know what `gauge` means!
—
Also, adding the label selector results in `unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: Metric label: "area" is not allowed'`. I want to respond to the heap size.

Comment: Aha! Interesting. So it is using `prometheus.googleapis.com` (GMP is exporting the metric to Google Cloud Monitoring) not `custom.googleapis.com` which makes sense to me.

Comment: It makes sense that it's using a Prometheus [gauge](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge) because the value of memory used can both increase and decrease.

Comment: So, the outstanding issue is that you've been unable to specify the Prometheus label (`area`) and value (`heap`), correct?

Comment: @DazWilkin thanks for all the help, BTW! Indeed, my main concern now is how to specify the label.

Comment: I went to read Stackdriver adapter's code and found [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/blob/master/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter/pkg/adapter/translator/query_builder.go#L43): `allowedCustomMetricsLabelPrefixes  = []string{"metric.labels"}`

So I added `metric.labels` to the metric name in the selector, and it worked! Thank you for all the help, guys!

Comment: Congrats @brandizzi! Which documentation you were looking at before? I think this is not documented.

Comment: @Mark I was searching all over the internet for instructions. My main references were GCP documentation pages (e.g. https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/hpa) but indeed I didn't find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change three things for getting it to work:

1. Add proper prefix and suffix to the metric name;
2. Use a `selector` clause for filtering metrics by label; and
3. Add the proper prefix to the metric label name.

### Prometheus metrics have a prefix and a suffix

From [Horizontal pod autoscaling (HPA)  |  Operations Suite  |  Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/hpa)

> Prometheus metrics are stored with the following conventions:
>
> - The prefix `prometheus.googleapis.com`.
> - This suffix is usually one of `gauge`, `counter`, `summary`, or `histogram`, although `untyped` metrics might have the `unknown` or `unknown:counter` suffix. To verify the suffix, look up the metric in Cloud Monitoring by using Metrics Explorer.

So I did it, went to Metrics Explorer, enabled the build and went to search for the metrics I wanted to use:

[image: An screenshot of Metrics Explorer showing how to find the metrics "full name"]

### Using a selector for metric labels

I wanted to filter by the `area` label, but we should not pass it in the name of the metrics. Filtering by labels should be done by using a `selector` in the `metric` clause.

Also...

### Metric label names have a prefix

We cannot just add a metric name to the `matchLabels` / `matchExpressions`. Every metric label name should be prefixed by `metric.labels.`:

```yaml
metric:
  name: prometheus.googleapis.com|jvm_memory_bytes_used|gauge
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        area: heap
```

The end result is this:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-autoscale
  namespace: somenamespace
spec:
  maxReplicas: 3
  metrics:
  - pods:
      metric:
        name: prometheus.googleapis.com|jvm_memory_bytes_used|gauge
        selector:
           matchLabels:
             metric.labels.area: heap
      target:
        averageValue: 2G
        type: AverageValue
  type: Pods
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-java-app
```

With that, I managed to make HPA respond to the custom metrics.

Comment: This is good sleuthing! I was unable to find it documented anywhere.  Interestingly, if you use a valid metric label, the query reported by `kubectl logs deployment/custom-metrics-stackdriver-adapter --namespace=custom-metrics --follow` isn't revised to include the `metric.label` even though e.g. `metric.label.pod` is included. But, if an erroneous label is used, errors are reported "Cannot find metric(s) that match ... label = {label} ...".

Comment: @DazWilkin Indeed, I didn't find it documented anywhere, so I had to rely on the source code. Quite annoying, but I'm glad it is done now :D